# managing an array

Tags: java, android

I want to save some that in an array and then use that . but the problem is that this is a large size data and I'm not sure if it's good idea or even possible to save all of that into an array . probably I should have some mechanism like deleting array items from the top ?

this is an android application and it's in real time so the speed is really important.

please help!

Comment: how big is "large size data" round about?

Comment: Big array (many small items), or big items?

Comment: Use ArrayList instead of Array..

Comment: the items are some numbers like 44.45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the amount of data that you are mentioning, there are still two possibilities. If you want your data to be stored persistently - go for SQLite without any second thoughts. If you don't want persistent storage - then `ArrayList` would be a better way to go rather than having an Array because performing operations on `ArrayList` would be much easier and faster(in certain cases),and you also won't have to keep changing your array size manually.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is the backing for a potentially large list of items you want to display, then I guess you will want to implement paging - to fetch data on demand a screenful at a time.

Comment: I have 10000 items in my array . what about array list ?